# Supertab inserts tabulation instead of autocompleting

Tags: autocompletion, plugin-supertab

I have [supertab](https://github.com/ervandew/supertab) installed alongside with [vim-go](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go).

Next, I'd like to have autocomplete when writing in Go, but when I press <kbd>tab</kbd> its literally inserts a tab character instead of showing the autocomplete prompt.

I tried to add the following in my `vimrc` but it didn't help:

```
let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType = "context"
```

or:

```
let g:SuperTabContextDefaultCompletionType = "<c-x><c-o>"
```

`<c-x><c-o>` works fine to start autocomplete, but I can't get anything with `tab`.

What am I doing wrong here?

**UPD** `:verbose imap <Tab>` result is:

```
i  <Tab>         <Plug>SuperTabForward
        Last set from ~/.vim/plugged/supertab/plugin/supertab.vim line 
1011
```

Comment: I tried your first line `"context"` with a minimal installation. After a restart of vim `fmt.<tab>` showed the omni completion candidates. For debugging try to use supertab without the context feature by setting in your vimrc `let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType = "<c-x><c-o>"` (none of the one you posted). This should try only omni completion on tab. You should also add to your question the result of `:imap <Tab>`.

Comment: @Hotschke Thanks. I have tried to add `let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType = "<c-x><c-o>"` - but still the same result - pressing the TAB button after `ftm.` results to adding tabulation.
Also, I updated my Q with the `:verbose imap <Tab>` output.

Comment: This is  weird. Do you use a minimal setup: minimal vimrc and only the two plugins in question? Could you also add `$vim -version | head`, terminal/gui in use, OS? Maybe there is something wrong with the keycode sent to vim.

Comment: @Hotschke That's it! Thanks. Made new clean file without any plugins excepting `fatih/vim-go` and `ervandew/supertab` - and it works now. Now just will have to find which plugin brokes my setup :-) 
Maybe worth to add your comments as an answer - so I'll mark it as Accepted?

Comment: It was `set paste` option... Weird :-|

Comment: I am not sure whether the advice to disable other plugins qualifies as an answer. There is already the important question https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/how-do-i-debug-my-vimrc-file. The  answer https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2004/1292 already suggests to isolate plugin(s). I feel like this question should simply link to this for others who struggle to setup supertab and vim-go as well.

Comment: You can also post an answer with the solution to your problem!

Comment: BTW there is a faq in the README.md of supertab mentioning the following: "make sure you don't have the `paste` option enabled in your vimrc or elsewhere."

Comment: @setevoy self-answering is a part of the SE model; please post your solution as an answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Hotschke's comments.

1. run vim without any plugins/options excepting `supertab` and `vim-go`
2. enable options/plugins one-by-one
3. find that the `set paste` option was the cause

Useful links related to this "issue":

https://github.com/ervandew/supertab/blob/master/README.rst

> make sure you don't have the paste option enabled in your vimrc or elsewhere

[How do I debug my vimrc file?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/how-do-i-debug-my-vimrc-file/2004#2004)